# Connecting repeater to access point

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, repeater

just bought a new router and repeater for a wifi hotspot i am currently running.. I thought i was havng problems with the repeater after i change from router to a server, (and i'm now using a router in bridge mode) so the server is managing all the dhcp.. etc, Hence, the router is Running as an access point. For some reason, repeaters, do connect to the access point apparently, but when connecting the client to the repeater (instead of access point) I can't get internet access. although i do get access to the repeater setup.and  access point setup too.. Any Idea what i'm doing wrong? or if that is the fact that repeaters must be connected to a router, not access point? thanks in advance. or should I use it as a WDS? or AP-wds?
I have a Cisco Lynksys e1200 router (which i'm using as access point) and an Encore ENXWI-1AN45 3 in one range extender